# Better way to compare SystemD version

Tags: bash, systemd

Systemd version 226 or higher support `TasksMax` option. I am using `systemctl --version | awk 'FNR==1 {print $2}'` to obtain the numerical version of systemd and compare it with 226. Is there a better way to know if the systemd installed support this option?

BTW, is there a better way than `sed -i` to comment/uncomment (enable/disable) an option in the systemd unit file like `TasksMAX`?